# What's the use of casting NULL to SomeType* in C++?

Tags: c++11, pointers, null, static-cast, nullptr

I'm currently grinding through some third-party C++ code that looks rather odd to me (I started out with C++11). One of the many things that left me puzzled, are the many instances of `static_cast` from `NULL` to some pointer type:

```
SomeClass* someClassPtr = static_cast<SomeClass*>(NULL);
```

I know you can cast pointers e.g. from a base class pointer into a derived class pointer, but there is absolutely no inheritance going on here. As far as I can see, this should be enough:

```
SomeClass* someClassPtr = NULL;
```

But the only cases in this code, where `NULL` does not get casted to a specific pointer type, are pointers in vectors and other containers:

```
SomeOtherClass.vecOfSomeClassPtr[i] = NULL;
```

So my questions are:

- Is this simply old-style (or even C-style) code from before there was `nullptr`?
- Is/was casting `NULL` necessary for other things than down-/upcasting when working with inheritance?
- Or am I missing something completely?

And in case I haven't gotten it wrong so far:
I first replaced all instances of `static_cast<type*>(NULL)` with `NULL` and later `nullptr`, to see if that would break anything: Nope.
The compiler doesn't protest and the program still seems to work as expected.
But I know pointers can be tricky little bastards, so:

- What pitfalls about the use of `nullptr` did I probably miss?

PS: Yes, I did use the search and yes, I did find similar questions on C code.
But this is C++ code and I wanted to know for sure, instead of just assuming something.

Comment: You have a lot of questions in one question.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What's the use of casting NULL to SomeType* in C++?
>
> ```
> SomeClass* someClassPtr = static_cast<SomeClass*>(NULL);
> ```

The cast has no effect in this context.

However more generally, it does make sense in some other context where overloading is involved:

```
void stupidly_overloaded_function(int);
void stupidly_overloaded_function(SomeClass*);
void stupidly_overloaded_function(SomeOtherClass*);

stupidly_overloaded_function(NULL);
```

which function gets called? It actually depends on the definition of `NULL`. Either it calls the `int` overload, or compilation fails due to ambiguity.

A cast can disambiguate the call:

```
stupidly_overloaded_function(static_cast<SomeClass*>(NULL));
```

I  think this is a significant reason for introducing `nullptr`. Although even `nullptr` cannot deal with multiple different pointer overloads, it does disambiguate between integers:

```
void not_quite_as_silly_overload(int);
void not_quite_as_silly_overload(SomeClass*);

not_quite_as_silly_overload(NULL);    // might call either overload
not_quite_as_silly_overload(nullptr); // unambiguously calls the pointer overload
```

Another case in C is macros involved with sizes of objects, such as the `container_of` macro from the Linux kernel:

```
define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({                      \
       const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);    \
       (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

Here, just 0 is used instead of `NULL`. I *think* that this could be implemented in C++ without the cast, but only using `declval` which was introduced in C++11.

---

> Is this simply old-style (or even C-style) code from before there was nullptr?

No, there was no universal style for such redundant casts. Your example has no overloading, so the above case does not apply to it.

> Is/was casting NULL necessary for other things than down-/upcasting when working with inheritance?

No, it was (and still is in the case of different pointer overloads) necessary for overload resolution.

Comment: So I should be careful with replacing those casts in function calls, but it should be save to do so in assignments.

Comment: @Floriel definitely safe in assignments to same type of pointer. Probably safe for function calls as long as you use `nullptr`. If overload fails, you see that at build time.