# Why doesn't implicit conversion occur on a typecasted nullptr

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, static-assert

I was trying to find a way to statically assert that a derived class pointer can safely be reinterpreted as a pointer to a base class, when I came across something unexpected:

I would have expected two of the static asserts in the following code to fail.

```
class Base1 {
    int x;
};
class Base2 {
    int y;
};
class Derived : public Base1, public Base2 {
    int z;
};

// one of these should fail???
static_assert( (Derived *)nullptr == (Base1 *)nullptr, "err1" );
static_assert( (Derived *)nullptr == (Base2 *)nullptr, "err2" );
// and one of these as well???
static_assert( (Base1 *)(Derived *)nullptr == nullptr, "err3" );
static_assert( (Base2 *)(Derived *)nullptr == nullptr, "err3" );
```

For the first pair of assertions, since its arguments are of type `Derived*` and `Base1*`/`Base2*`, I would have expected the `Derived*` to be implicitly converted to a `Base1*` or `Base2*` for the comparison. Since `Base1` and `Base2` can't occupy the same memory, they can't both be located at the start of the memory a `Derived` object occupies, so one of those conversions should have increased the pointer value. The non-zero pointer then shouldn't have been found to be equal to null.

Similarly, for the second pair, I would expect the explicit cast to `Base1*` and `Base2*` should have altered one of the pointers, but they still compared equal to null.

What is going on here?

Comment: This is like asking why `int a = 0; long b = 0; static_assert(a == b);` works.  All of your points equal `nullptr` so they should all be equal.

Comment: I think nullptr are always the same value. And casting them has no effect in the case. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44117520/7834933

Comment: However this will have the intended effect if those aren't nullptr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A null pointer is always a null pointer, and it stays a null pointer.

> **[conv.ptr]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.ptr#3) A prvalue of type “pointer to cv `D`”, where `D` is a class
>   type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv `B`”, where
>   `B` is a base class of `D`. If `B` is an inaccessible or ambiguous
>   base class of `D`, a program that necessitates this conversion is
>   ill-formed. The result of the conversion is a pointer to the base
>   class subobject of the derived class object. **The null pointer value
>   is converted to the null pointer value of the destination type**.

Since comparing a `Derived*` to a `Base*` requires converting them to a common type, this is the conversion that will happen. And as you can see, it's null value preserving.

The rationale for this is that it should not be possible to produce a valid looking value from a null pointer value. If you started with a null pointer value, your are gonna stay with it.

Comment: I'd (nullptr)+1 but that'd be UB.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the [C-style cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast):

Let's review the following quote:

> When the C-style cast expression is encountered, the compiler attempts to interpret it as the following cast expressions, in this order:
>   a) `const_cast<new_type>(expression)`
>   b) `static_cast<new_type>(expression)`

If you try to use `reinterpret_cast`, [it will fail compilation](https://godbolt.org/z/RJ9EZU) because `reinterpret_cast` is not a constant expression, but `static_cast` is does more than just cast for the type system. In this case `static_cast` likely tells the compiler to perform some offset based on the (known at compile-time) sizes of `Base1`, `Base2`, and `Derived`, but static_cast [may involve implicit conversions, a call to the constructor of new_type or a call to a user-defined conversion operator.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)

Additionally, the text from `static_cast` also states the following:

> 2)  If new_type is a pointer or reference to some class D and the type of expression is a pointer or reference to its non-virtual base B, static_cast performs a downcast. This downcast is ill-formed if B is ambiguous, inaccessible, or virtual base (or a base of a virtual base) of D.
>
> 9) A pointer to member of some class D can be upcast to a pointer to
>   member of its unambiguous, accessible base class B. This static_cast
>   makes no checks to ensure the member actually exists in the runtime
>   type of the pointed-to object.

This is actually because the layout of `Derived` is known in it's entirety, and while this layout is technically implementation defined, the compiler knows this layout precisely since neither `Base1` nor `Base2` are inaccessible or virtual bases.

We can actually see a case where this fails by providing an inaccessible base:

```
class Base{};

class Base1 : public Base
{
    int x;
};

class Base2 : public Base
{
    int y;
};

class Derived 
    : public Base1
    , public Base2 
{
    int z;
};

constexpr static Derived d{};

constexpr static const Derived* derived_ptr = &d;
constexpr static const Base1* base1_ptr = &d;
constexpr static const Base2* base2_ptr = &d;

// fail due to inaccessible base
static_assert(static_cast<const Derived*>(nullptr) == static_cast<const Base*>(nullptr), "err1" ); // fails
static_assert(static_cast<const Derived*>(derived_ptr) == static_cast<const Base*>(nullptr), "err2" ); // fails

// succeed
static_assert(static_cast<const Derived*>(derived_ptr) == static_cast<const Base1*>(base1_ptr), "err3" );
static_assert(static_cast<const Derived*>(derived_ptr) == static_cast<const Base2*>(base2_ptr), "err4" );
// and one of these as well???
static_assert(static_cast<const Base1*>(static_cast<const Derived*>(derived_ptr)) == base1_ptr, "err5" );
static_assert(static_cast<const Base2*>(static_cast<const Derived*>(derived_ptr)) == base2_ptr, "err6" );
```